# using while loop with nokogiri to navigate to next page

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have written code that scrapes and parses the information on this site => www.africancollective.come/brows/african-literature/fiction

```
require 'ruby gems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'ap'
require 'debugger'
require 'csv'

#collect all the authors, books, ISBN, publisher info
#====================================================
url = 'http://www.africanbookscollective.com/browse/african-literature/fiction'
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

# create an array for every book content on each page that has element of form
# [<ISBN Number>, <Book Pages>, <Book Dimensions>, <First Published>, <Publisher>,<CoverType>]
# save array into a csv file with the columns of:
# <ISBN Number> <Book Pages> <Book Dimensions> <First Published> <Publisher> <CoverType>

# opens a csv file and shovels column titles into the first row
CSV.open("bookinfo.csv", "w+") do |csv|
  csv << ["ISBN Number", "Book Pages", "Book Dimensions", "First Published", "Publisher", "CoverType"]
end

# initializes another_page and page_num varaibles
page_num = 0

# the while loop runs as long as the statement below evaluates to true
#while page_num < 390
new_page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.africanbookscollective.com/browse/african-studies?b_start:int=#{page_num+10}&amp;-C="))
  # search for the context-details of each book
  books = page.css('p.context-details').map do |book|
    book.text.gsub(/\s{2,}/, "").chomp.split(" |")
  end


  #appends context-details onto the csv we already created
  CSV.open("bookinfo.csv", "a+") do |csv|
    books.each do |book|
      csv << book
    end
  end
  page_num += 10
#end
    enter code here
```

This code only gets me the information on the 1st page; it fails to grab all the rest of the pages (1 - 38).  I think this has something to do with the way my while loop is structured, right?

Why isn't it moving on to the next page using the format in the string interpolation 
provided in new_page?

Thank you

Comment: It should be `"http://www.africanbookscollective.com/browse/african-studies?b_start:int=#{page_num}&amp;-C="`

Comment: Tried your suggestion before posting and it didn't work.

Comment: `books = page.css('p.context-details')` change to `books = new_page.css('p.context-details')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the numbers and iterate by following the "next" links. It should look something like this:

```
# page 1
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(start_url))
do_something_with page

# repeat until no more "next" links
while a = page.at('a[title="Next page"]')
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(a[:href]))
  do_something_with page
end
```

Comment: hello! Just tried your suggestion but got the error `undefined local variable or method start_url' for main:Object (NameError)`.  Can you please clarify what start_url stands for? Thank you

Comment: How about if you take a guess which url is the start_url ?

Comment: start_url would be `"http://africanbookscollective.com/browse/african-studies?b_start:int=0&amp;-C="`

Am I right? If so how would nokogiri know what the Next page is? ASk because I have inspected the page and there isn't a link pointing to the next page on it. 

Apologize for the noob questions …still trying to understand how certain things work. Thank you for helping

Comment: The start_url is the first url, obviously. The 'next' link is there and I don't know why you can't see it.

Comment: Yeah, you are right … I missed the 'Next page" link for some reason. Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. Your answer helped a great deal.